# How to put a pokemon in a gym which is being attacked?

Tags: pokemon-go

Sometimes, if I approach a friendly gym which is currently under attack, and try to put an extra defender into the gym, I will be unable to do so, and the game will tell me "The gym is under attack".

However, sometimes when I am battling an enemy gym, i see someone walk past with a phone in their hand, and when I finish my current battle, I notice that they have put an extra defender into the gym while I was battling.

1. Is it supposed to be possible to put an extra defender in a gym while an enemy is battling that gym?
2. If so how?
3. If not, is there any way I can prevent that from happening while I am fighting gyms?

Comment: From personal experience there is a bug when gyms are newly defeated. A priority is given to the individual(s) in the last battle which took the gym which gives them some time to add their own Pokémon without being sniped. The bug is that after they have inserted their Pokémon others from the same team still have to wait ten+ minutes before they can add their own. The message given says that the gym is under attack, even when it isn't.

Comment: Question part 3 does not make sense because you are assuming adding a defender during battle is not possible, then ask how to prevent it.

Comment: @Gwellin This bug has happened to me as well when I defeated a gym. It wouldn't let me put a Pokemon in because it was under attack. I looked around, and it was definitely not under attack. I tried to explain that gyms are buggy in my answer below.

Comment: @Gwelin That is another unrelated issue which has a well-known workaround (if everyone who wants to put a pokemon into the gym count down and push the button to put the pokemon in at the same time, that issue will not happen). But this question is about something different (about adding defenders to gyms which are actually being attacked).

Comment: @Jerry I don't agree. It is at least under some circumstances possible to add defenders while a gym is under attack. I mentioned in the question that I have experienced people adding defenders while I am attacking a gym. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: @Alderath, I am simply pointing out that the grammar does not make sense.  When starting with "If not," part 3 assumes the opposite of the previous sentence.  If that is not what you meant, please edit.

Comment: @Jerry What I meant is: If it is **not supposed to be possible** to add a defender while a gym is being attacked (but **in practice**, it is possible in some way, because it has happened to me), is there any way I can prevent enemies from adding a defender to gyms while I am fighting gyms? (Ie. as an attacking player, is there anything I can do to make sure that the "gym is under attack" block works like it is supposed to do?)

Comment: I believe the gym is not considered under attack until at least one pokemon has been knocked out. Until that happens, other people on the opponent team can still add more to the gym. To prevent it from happening, you may want to prioritize knocking out one pokemon first before going on to the rest.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that after you take over a gym, and put a Pokemon into it, any players on the same team as you will **NOT** be able to put another defender in for 10 minutes. Niantic is working on a fix.

I did hear from another website that this may have been implemented to prevent gym shaving, but I don't know if that's true or not.

**UPDATE:** This issue has been fixed.

Comment: This isn't what OP is asking about. Furthermore, I've found a way to circumvent that issue when you're with friends. This is about opponents putting Pokémon in a gym while you're attacking it.

Comment: Niantic is rolling out an update fixing the issue, it should not be a problem anymore. (Newest version shown on their twitter and website)